# How do I increase the font size in YaST2 on openSUSE 13.2?

Tags: yast, opensuse-13.2

[image: screenshot of YaST2 in comparison to other applications]

The font size in that application is eyestrainingly small for me to work with. How do I set it to a size of my choice?

Comment: Does it use qt? If so, use qtconfig in terminal.

Comment: Changing font size with `qtconfig` (or rather, `kdesu qtconfig`, since YaST2 runs as root) works in other Qt (plain, not KDE) applications, such as avidemux2_qt4, cuneiform-qt, flo, juffed, kchmviewer, openpref, qasconfig, qashctl, qasmixer, qlipper, qpdfview, qtconfig itself, quiterss, qvlc, qxkb, simsu, virtualbox-qt, zint-qt, but not in YaST2.

Comment: Try to use `/usr/lib/qt3/bin/qtconfig` as root, as YaST2 may still be a Qt3 application.

Comment: I didn't have any Qt3 applications or libraries installed, so this is a dead end. To be sure, I installed package `qt3` and tested with `/usr/lib/qt3/bin/qtconfig`, but as expected this has no effect on YaST2.

Comment: What about kcontrol?

Comment: kcontrol is for KDE3 and does not even run properly anymore, this is a dead end. I have used systemsettings, the KDE4 successor, to change application styles and fonts. This applies to both KDE4 applications and plain Qt applications. YaST2 remains unaffected.

Comment: qtconfig is mentioned everywhere as the solution to Yast2 font size. Try to launch it from a real root login rather than via kdesu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is

```
[super-user-command]
super-user-command=sudo
```

in `~/.kde4/share/config/kdesurc`. When that configuration item is either removed, or the full path to the sudo binary is supplied, application styles and font settings work in YaST2, too.

Comment: So this WAS a problem of kdesu, and my comment above that I deleted when you posted your answer was correct after all. So I put it up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

qtconfig is mentioned everywhere as the solution to Yast2 font size.
Try to launch it from a real root login rather than via kdesu.